# Finding median of large set of numbers too big to fit into memory

Tags: algorithm

I was asked this question in an interview recently.

There are N numbers, too many to fit into memory. They are split across k database tables (unsorted), each of which can fit into memory. Find the median of all the numbers.

Wasn't quite sure about the answer to this one.

Comment: divide and conquer my friend, divide and conquer

Comment: If the numbers are integers, answers to this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572640/interview-question-find-median-from-mega-number-of-integers/3576479#3576479

Comment: Do you know the distribution?  If it's normal or uniform, the median would equal the mean - no sorting necessary.

Answer (score 12):

There's a few potential solutions:

- External merge sort - O(n log n)
  You basically sort the numbers on the first pass, then find the median on the second.
- Order statistics distributed selection algorithm - O(n)
  Simplify the problem to the original problem of    finding the kth number in an unsorted array.
- Counting sort histogram O(n)
  You have to assume some properties about the range of the numbers - can the range fit in the memory?
- If anything is known about the distribution of the numbers other
  algorithms can be produced.

For more details and implementation see:
http://www.fusu.us/2013/07/median-in-large-set-across-1000-servers.html

Answer (score 9):

### This answer on quora explains the whole process clearly step by step http://qr.ae/dMkGc. Simply copying it down for non Quorans

Suppose you have a master node (or are able to use a consensus protocol to elect a master from among your servers).  The master first queries the servers for the size of their sets of data, call this n, so that it knows to look for the k = n/2 largest element.

The master then selects a random server and queries it for a random element from the elements on that server.  The master broadcasts this element to each server, and each server partitions its elements into those larger than or equal to the broadcasted element and those smaller than the broadcasted element.

Each server returns to the master the size of the larger-than partition, call this m.  If the sum of these sizes is greater than k, the master indicates to each server to disregard the less-than set for the remainder of the algorithm.  If it is less than k, then the master indicates to disregard the larger-than sets and updates k = k - m.  If it is exactly k, the algorithm terminates and the value returned is the pivot selected at the beginning of the iteration.

If the algorithm does not terminate, recurse beginning with selecting a new random pivot from the remaining elements.

Analysis:

Let n be the total number of elements and s be the number of servers.  Assume that the elements are roughly randomly and evenly distributed among servers (each server has O(n/s) elements).  In iteration i, we expect to do about O(n/(s*2^i)) work on each server, as the size of each servers element sets will be approximately cut in half (remember, we assumed roughly random distribution of elements) and O(s) work on the master (for broadcasting/receiving messages and adding the sizes together).  We expect O(log(n/s)) iterations.  Adding these up over all iterations gives an expected runtime of O(n/s + slog(n/s)), and assuming s << sqrt(n) which is normally the case, this becomes simply (O(n/s)), which is the best you could possibly hope for.

Note also that this works not just for finding the median but also for finding the kth largest value for any value of k.

Comment: upvote for doing the right thing: copying and attributing!

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the "Median of Medians" algorithm in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians).

Related question: [Median-of-medians in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790360/median-of-medians-in-java).

Explanation: [http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960130.html](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eeppstein/161/960130.html)

Comment: Does this require all the sublists to be the same size? What if they are not?

Comment: Good question. Probably. You could of course also process each table 5 (or 7, ..) rows at a time... But then I suppose you may be violating the memory constraints.

Comment: @aioobe, the number set is too large to fit into the memory, so even if we can find the `median of medians`, how can we do the `quick select` ?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! This question has been asked many times and "Use 'Median of Medians'" answer has been given many times, but this is the first time I've found someone who provided an explanation. (Wikipedia's article struck me as a little too... obtuse?)

Comment: I might be missing something, but isn't Median of Medians gives only an approximate median? Especially if the groups have different size or if there are repeating elements.

E.g., groups (1,1,2); (10,100,1000); (1001,1002,1003,1004,1005), medians would be 1,100,1003 respectively gives "median" 100, while the correct median is 1000.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at this is to go back to the definition of "median."  Authors vary in their language, but basically the median is the value which splits a probability distribution into two equal parts.

So instead of spending a lot of effort sorting enormous data sets, estimate the distribution and find the middle.  As noted above for some distributions the median equals the mean, which is quick and easy to compute.  Also, if an exact answer isn't necessary you can use the empirical relationship: mean - mode = 3 * (mean - median).

Comment: Can you link to the source for mean - mode = 3 * (mean - median)? Thanks for this answer, I like the approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

1. Sample the data to get a general idea about the distribution.
2. Using the information about the distribution, choose a "bucket" (a range), large enough to get the median inside and small enough to fit into the memory.
3. With one pass (O(N)) count the numbers before the bucket (L1_size), after the bucket (L3_size) and put numbers within the range into the bucket (L2). You will see if the chosen bucket contains the median. If not - go to step 2.
4. Use quickselect or other method to find the k=(L1_size + L2_size/2) element in the bucket.

Requires O(N) + O(L2_size) steps.

Answer (score 0):

I was also asked the same question and i couldn't tell an exact answer so after the interview i went through some books on interviews and here is what i found.

> Example: Numbers are randomly generated and stored into an (expanding) array. How
>   wouldyoukeep track of the median?
>
> Our data structure brainstorm might look like the following:
>
> • Linked list? Probably not. Linked lists tend not to do very well with accessing and
>   sorting numbers.
>
> • Array? Maybe, but you already have an array. Could you somehow keep the elements
>   sorted? That's probably expensive. Let's hold off on this and return to it if it's needed.
>
> • Binary tree? This is possible, since binary trees do fairly well with ordering. In fact, if the binary search tree is perfectly balanced, the top might be the median. But, be careful—if there's an even number of elements, the median is actually the average
>   of the middle two elements. The middle two elements can't both be at the top. This is probably a workable algorithm, but let's come back to it.
>
> • Heap? A heap is really good at basic ordering and keeping track of max and mins.
>   This is actually interesting—if you had two heaps, you could keep track of the bigger
>   half and the smaller half of the elements. The bigger half is kept in a min heap, such
>   that the smallest element in the bigger half is at the root.The smaller half is kept in a
>   max heap, such that the biggest element of the smaller half is at the root. Now, with
>   these data structures, you have the potential median elements at the roots. If the
>   heaps are no longer the same size, you can quickly "rebalance" the heaps by popping
>   an element off the one heap and pushing it onto the other.
>
> Note that the more problems you do, the more developed your instinct on which data
>   structure to apply will be. You will also develop a more finely tuned instinct as to which of these approaches is the most useful.

Answer (score -1):

If an approximate answer is sufficient, a method similar to @piccolbo works well. I'll assume all the points are integers, but if not you can multiply by ten or a hundred or whatever to normalize the data to integers. Make one pass over the data calculating an average (arithmetic mean. Call that number the provisional median. Then make a second pass over the data. If the data point is less than the provisional median, reduce the provisional median by one. If the data point is greater than the provisional median, increase the provisional median by one. If the data point is the same as the provisional median, leave the provisional median unchanged. After the end of the data, return the provisional median. What will happen is that the provisional median will initially change from time to time, but eventually it will stabilize over a very small range, which will be very close to the actual median.