# Interview Question: How to fulfill max number of Moving Requests

Tags: algorithm, graph

There are N Buildings on the site ranging from 0 to N-1. Every employee has an office space in one of the buildings. A new employee may make request to move from current building X to another building Y. A moving request is noted by

```
class Request {
    String employeeName;
    int fromBuilding;
    int toBuilding;
}
```

Initially all buildings are full. A request from building X to building Y is achievable only if someone in Building Y makes an achievable request to move therefore creating a vacancy. Given a wishlist of requests help us plan for the best way of building swaps. A plan that fulfills maximum number of requests is considered the best.

```
Example 1:

Input:
["Alex", 1, 2]
["Ben", 2, 1]
["Chris", 1, 2]
["David", 2, 3]
["Ellen", 3, 1]
["Frank", 4, 5] 

Output: [["Alex", "Bem"], ["Chris", "David", "Ellen"]]
```

```
Example 2:

Input:
["Adam", 1, 2]
["Brian", 2, 1]
["Carl", 4, 5]
["Dan", 5, 1]
["Eric", 2, 3]
["Fred", 3, 4]

Output: [["Adam", "Eric", "Fred", "Carl", "Dan"]]
```

This question was taken from leet code here:

https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/325840/amazon-phone-screen-moving-requests

I am trying to do this in python and I figured that creating a dictionary that represents the graph would be a good start but not sure what to do next.

````
```
def findMovers(buildReqs):
    graph={}
    for i in buildReqs:
        if i[1] not in graph:
            graph[i[1]]=[i[2]]
        else:
            graph[i[1]].append(i[2])
```
````

Comment: Please read [ask], this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Stack Overflow exists to help programmers learn and provide a standard repository for programming problems, both simple and complex. Hope you are downvoting all questions similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572640/interview-question-find-median-from-mega-number-of-integers?rq=1

Comment: That's almost a decade old, things change over time. I'd suggest you take the [tour].

Comment: @jonrsharpe here is a quote from the link you just sent: "Ask about...

Specific programming problems
Software algorithms
Coding techniques
Software development tools" I believe my question is a "Specific programming problem". Have a nice day.

Comment: There's nothing specific about *"not sure what to do next"*.

Answer (score 0):

Make a bipartite graph with current offices on one side and future offices on the other.

Draw edges with score 0 for people staying in their current office, and edges with score 1 for people moving into any desired new office.

Find the maximum weight bipartite matching: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

Comment: I'm a little confused too. Wouldn't current offices and future offices be the same? And we don't know "people staying in their current office" right? That, and people who are moving, are what we want to find? My initial thoughts were that we would create a directed graph and find the cycles in that graph?

Comment: @user3386109 office 1 gets matched with office 2, office 2 gets matched with office 3, office 3 gets matched with office 1.  The augmenting paths you find with, Ford Fulkerson or whatever will create the cycles you expect to see.