# Is it possible to compute median while data is still being generated? Python online median calculator

Tags: python, median

I've seen a broader version of this question asked, where the individual was looking for more than one summary statistic, but I have not seen a solution presented. I'm only interested in the median, in Python, here.

Let's say I'm generating a million values in a loop. I cannot save the million values into a list and compute median once I'm done, because of memory issues. Is it possible to compute median as I go? For mean, I'd just sum values progressively, and once done divide by a million. For median the answer does not seem as intuitive.

I'm stuck on the "thought experiment" section of this, so I haven't been able to really try anything that I think might work. I'm not sure if this is an algorithm that has been implemented, but I can't find it if it has been.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interview Question: Find Median From Mega Number Of Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572640/interview-question-find-median-from-mega-number-of-integers)

Comment: I don't think so. I'm trying to understand the solution, and my question seems different a few ways:

1) I'm generating the values that I want to compute the median for in a loop, and in Python. Python seems to have high memory overhead for list/dict construction, so saving the values appears memory prohibitive. 
2) There's no value for me in saving the values I compute in each loop. If I can dump them, that's ideal.
3) I think this solution requires me to sort a list. I'm unable to generate a list of the size I need in Python due to memory overhead.

Comment: Are you running this on some pocket calculator, or why are a million values memory prohibitive?

Comment: What is the range of possible values?  The smaller it is, the easier this is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't be possible unless your idea of "values" is restricted in some exploitable way; and/or you can make more than one pass over the data; and/or you're willing to store stuff on disk too. Suppose you know there are 5 values, all distinct integers, and you know the first 3 are 5, 6, 7. The median will be one of those, but at this point you can't know which one, so you have to remember all of them. If 1 and 2 come next, the median is 5; if 4 and 8 next, 6; if 8 and 9 next, it's 7.

This obviously generalizes to any odd number of values `range(i, i + 2*N+1)`, at the point you've seen the first `N+1` of them:  the median can turn out to be any one of those first `N+1`, so unless there's something exploitable about the nature of the values, you have to remember all of them at that point.

An example of something exploitable: you know there are at most 100 *distinct* values. Then you can use a dict to count how many of each appear, and easily calculate the median at the end from that compressed representation of the distribution.

### Approximating

For reasons already mentioned, there is no "shortcut" here to be had in general. But I'll attach Python code for a reasonable one-pass approximation method, as detailed in ["The Remedian: A Robust Averaging Method for Large Data Sets"](https://wis.kuleuven.be/stat/robust/papers/publications-1990/rousseeuwbassett-remedian-jasa-1990.pdf). That paper also points to other approximation methods.

The key: pick an odd integer `B` greater than 1. Then successive elements are stored in a buffer until `B` of them have been recorded. At that point, the median of those advances to the next level, and the buffer is cleared. Their median remains the only memory of those `B` elements retained.

The same pattern continues at deeper levels too:  after `B` of those median-of-`B` medians have been recorded, the median of *those* advances to the next level, and the second-level buffer is cleared. The median advanced then remains the only memory of the `B**2` elements that went into it.

And so on.  At worst it can require storing `B * log(N, B)` values, where `N` is the total number of elements. In Python it's easy to code it so buffers are created as needed, so `N` doesn't need to be known in advance.

If `B >= N`, the method is exact, but then you've also stored every element. If `B < N`, it's an approximation to the median. See the paper for details - it's quite involved. Here's a case that makes it look very good ;-)

```
>>> import random
>>> xs = [random.random() for i in range(1000001)]
>>> sorted(xs)[500000] # true median
0.5006315438367565
>>> w = MedianEst(11)
>>> for x in xs:
...     w.add(x)
>>> w.get()
0.5008443883489089
```

Perhaps surprisingly, it does worse if the inputs are added in sorted order:

```
>>> w.clear()
>>> for x in sorted(xs):
...     w.add(x)
>>> w.get()
0.5021045181828147
```

User beware! Here's the code:

```
class MedianEst:
    def __init__(self, B):
        assert B > 1 and B & 1
        self.B = B
        self.half = B >> 1
        self.clear()

    def add(self, x):
        for xs in self.a:
            xs.append(x)
            if len(xs) == self.B:
                x = sorted(xs)[self.half]
                xs.clear()
            else:
                break
        else:
            self.a.append([x])

    def get(self):
        total = 0
        weight = 1
        accum = []
        for xs in self.a:
            total += len(xs) * weight
            accum.extend((x, weight) for x in xs)
            weight *= self.B
        # `total` elements in all
        limit = total // 2 + 1
        total = 0
        for x, weight in sorted(accum):
            total += weight
            if total >= limit:
                return x

    def clear(self):
        self.a = []
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I've done a lot of thinking, and, in addition to reading the responses, it does not sound like what I'm asking is possible. I'm upvoting this answer, but I don't want to mislead future readers into thinking that what I'm asking is possible, so I won't be accepting the answer.

Comment: Well, whether you accept it is up to you, but your question's title asked _whether_ it's possible. Seems to me that "no, but ..." is an answer to what you asked ;-)